# In asp.net mvc, where do I put my strongly typed viewdata reference in my viewpage?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, viewdata

My viewpage doesn't have a codebehind, so how do I tell it to use a strongly typed viewdata?

Answer (score 8):

Just in header:

```
<%@ Page Title="" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/Views/Shared/Site.Master" 
            Inherits="System.Web.Mvc.ViewPage<HomePageViewModel>" %>
```

Then you can access your strongly typed model like this:

```
<%= Model.Username %>
```

"Model" property is automatically cast to your type.

Answer (score 1):

You can of course create a strongly typed viewdata by inheriting from it and adding a .cs file like this:

1. Create a .cs file (i.e.: if you have "Index.aspx" call it "Index.cs") next to your view.
2. Create a class that inherits from the System.Web.Mvc.ViewPage class
3. Modify the aspx file to inherit from it:

   <%@ Page Title="" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/Views/Shared/Site.Master" Inherits="MyNamespace.MyViewPage" %>